# How to enable find_path() to search for the directory outside current package?

Tags: cmake

I'm building a project containing multiple repos/packages.

The project structure shows as below.

```
     Top level directory
             |
    -------------------
    |        |        |
  ament     app <--- lib
```

Library **lib** is linked to **app**. Thus I put a `Findlib.cmake` under **app**.
Inside `Findlib.cmake`, I call `find_path()` to search the path to source code and header file in **lib**.

However, it seems that `find_path()` in **app** is unable to find the stuff in **lib** since **lib** is outside **app** repo, unless I add `HINTS` in `find_path()` to indicate the absolute path of **lib**.

But it is unnecessary to call `find_path()` in **app** at all if I directly provide the path to **lib**. Instead, I prefer to provide `find_path()` with some CMake standard variables/definitions, such as `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`.

Could you please tell me how to enable `find_path()` to search for the directory outside current packages?

Thank you.

Best regards,

David

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find out a CMAKE variable to indicate the root directory.
The only solution is to add the directory of **lib** into `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

`cmake ... -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=path/to/lib`

The other way is to adjust the structure of this project instead.
Create a `thirdparty` folder under **app**. Put the **lib** package under `thirdparty`.